# postgresql pg_dump out of memory

Tags: postgresql, backup, memory, pg-dump

is it possible to limit somehow usage of resources for pg_dump?

The problem is, whole DBase is 775GB and i have two very large tables:

pg_largeobject table is – 390GB

```
pg_largeobject statistics:
Index scans              778313505
Index tuples fetched    1079812292
Tuples inserted          201022148
Table size                  395 GB
Indexes size               6900 MB
```

hive.lob_messages – 265GB.

```
Index scans             194377937
Index tuples fetched    183894199
Tuples inserted          16902844
Table size  8127 MB
Toast table size     272573947904
Indexes size              3090 MB
```

In all cases I am executing this pg_dump command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d hive -Fc -v -f /nfs/hive_dump_10/hive_full_20191016_1945.dmp 2> /nfs/hive_dump_10/hive_full_20191016_1945.log
```

When i try to run pg_dump, to dump all the data it is killed by "out of memory".
My Postgre SQL server have had 20gb of RAMs and when I started a pg_dump, it kills after about ~30minutes. saying out of memory.

DB with 20GB of rams and pg_dump is killed by this *.log line:

```
pg_dump: reading large objects
```

Kern.log:

```
Oct 15 09:00:18 hive-psql kernel: [21504626.583951] Out of memory: Kill process 30663 (pg_dump) score 750 or sacrifice child
Oct 15 09:00:18 hive-psql kernel: [21504626.584000] Killed process 30663 (pg_dump) total-vm:19151692kB, anon-rss:16873728kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Here is ZABBIX monitoring tool showing my three times tried a pg dump with 20GB rams:
[image]

So to cope with the problem i gave my all resources, additional +20 GB ram (40gb in total), and the it kills after ~3hours by this *.log line:

```
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "hive.lob_messages"
```

And kern.log says:

```
Oct 16 23:19:01 hive-psql kernel: [15614.408113] Out of memory: Kill process 2693 (pg_dump) score 840 or sacrifice child
Oct 16 23:19:01 hive-psql kernel: [15614.408169] Killed process 2693 (pg_dump) total-vm:38363104kB, anon-rss:34020140kB, file-rss:24kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

ZABBIX window again, with 40GB in total:
[image]

I do not have any more resources for that.
So what are my options? My DB grows everyday, thank you.
I think that additional 20GB will be suffice, 60GB of rams it should be enough . But is this OK situation? What to do when my DB became like ~2TB in size and etc...

Other question, is my hive.lob_messages table is okay?
Table size and toast table size is different.

Comment: Is it the database server that goes OOM or the `pg_dump` client tool?

Comment: after executing command pg_dump after 30mins or 3hours respectivelly the terminal windows writes: Killed. cat /var/log/kern.log shows:

Comment: Oct 16 23:19:01 hive-psql kernel: [15614.408113] Out of memory: Kill process 2693 (pg_dump) score 840 or sacrifice child
Oct 16 23:19:01 hive-psql kernel: [15614.408169] Killed process 2693 (pg_dump) total-vm:38363104kB, anon-rss:34020140kB, file-rss:24kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Comment: You'll have to disable memory overcommit to get a proper OOM error.

Comment: i don't know what you mean: "collect a core dump and create a stack trace". But, first time pg_dump was killed at "retreiveing large objects" (pg_largeobject - 390GB) and after adding 20GB more, it was killed during on that table which is 265GB.

Comment: Forget about the stack trace. This is weird. Is this an old version of `pg_dump`?

Comment: psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Comment: The database server is virtual maschine, as i told by sys admins.

Comment: How many rows does pg_largeobject have?

Comment: jjanes, i have attached picture.

Comment: Gumuliokas, can you try by running pg_dump from any another server ,instead of this same server.

Answer (score 1):

What the graph shows is pg_dump probably starting at 19:45 and having a normal memory consumption until 20:00. At 20:00, it appears that ~30 GB are suddenly allocated and not much is released until 23:15 when presumably the Out-Of-Memory condition occurs.

From the comments, the kernel says:

```
hive-psql kernel: [15614.408169] Killed process 2693 (pg_dump) total-vm:38363104kB, anon-rss:34020140kB, file-rss:24kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

The `anon-rss` of pg_dump at about 36GB shows that it is indeed pg_dump that over-allocates. There is something wrong in pg_dump needing that much memory.

Your database surely has many large objects, some of them may be very large (the theorical maximum per object is 2TB) but pg_dump processes large objects by:

- opening a cursor on `SELECT oid FROM pg_largeobject_metadata ORDER BY 1` and reading it by chunks of 1000 entries: that should never blow up.
- for each large object, loop on lo_read to fetch the contents into a buffer of 16384 bytes: that should never blow up.

The fact that the table itself weighs 390 GB should not be a reason for pg_dump to do large allocations.

> *But, first time pg_dump was killed at "retreiveing large objects"*

Assuming pg_dump displays this with the `-v` options (by the way, you did not mention what options were passed), it should display *"reading large objects"* instead.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your message. I will edit my first post to answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres pg_dump sacrificed memory allocation check to speed up the back up process. pg_dump should be rewritten to take into account out of memory problem. What I did was let pg_dump backup non-blob fields then I wrote a program to backup blob fields separately. I had to write a restore program too.

Comment: This answer would be better with a) a reference to the code change assertion b) an explanation of how your custom code worked.